# Storing password (functions.php)

Tags: functions, password

I have created password form where visitors can access any password protected post with belonging password. Basically you enter unique password and you are redirected to a post which is protected with given password.
Everything works fine (with help from s_ha_dum), except one thing - you have to enter password twice.

functions.php :

```
function doPasswordStuff(){
    if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $post_password = trim($_POST['passwordfield']);
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
        if (!empty($post_id)) {
                wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id));
                exit();
        } else {
            // oh dear, there isnt a post with this 'password', put a redirect to a fallback here
            wp_redirect(xxx');
            exit();
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','doPasswordStuff');
```

Do you have any idea how to do this without entering password twice?

Comment: Well, the first time the password is entered, it is just being used as search criteria to obtain a post ID. Your code then redirects to that post. It's a protected post, so it will ask for a password. These 2 operations are completely separate. I'm not aware of any way to programmatically log in to a protected post in WP. You certainly cannot do it with wp_redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
function dopasswordstuff(){
   if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_password = trim($_POST['passwordfield']);
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %s", $post_password) );
    if (!empty($post_id)) {
      if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
      }
      // 10 days
      setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $post_password ) ), time() + 864000, COOKIEPATH );
      wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id));
    }
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','dopasswordstuff');
```

I [cribbed some stuff from the Core post login system](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-login.php#L403) and I believe I got it working. The trick is to set the cookie, which required adding this part:

```
if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {  
     require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' ); 
     // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
     $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
}
// 10 days
setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $post_password ) ), time() + 864000, COOKIEPATH );
```

Comment: I don't even know what to say man, thank you thousand times - this works perfectly.

Comment: Pretty impressive.